# k-means cluster 20000 points by assigned value using QGIS

Tags: qgis, clustering

I started with a pixel layer in QGIS which represents the demand for a given service with a resolution of 100m^2 for which I now want to derive a set of destinations that best serves this demand. My current plan is to use k-means clustering and run this with 10, 20, 30, and 40 clusters in order to see what the minimum number of clusters is for which the average distance from any one point to a cluster center is closest to 3km (a distance threshold defined within our project).

To do this I first turned the raster layer into a point layer - I now have approximately 19,000 points (each with an assigned demand attribute) distributed over an area of interest (circle with 50km radius). I would like to cluster these points such that the demand at each point is taken into account.

How do I do this?

I have tried to use the QGIS integrated k-means clustering function, and came up with a set of 20 clusters (as an example), but I think this approach doesn't take into account the demand at a given location (see screenshot).

I downloaded the attribute based clustering plugin, but when I tried to use this with almost 20k data points it seemed to get stuck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe one clarification that helps visualize how an output in this case could look like: each of the 19k points is attributed with a service demand at that location, so if these were points were clustered so that the sum total of demand is kept the same that should form smaller clusters in regions of high demand and vice versa which would be insightful. If there was a way to implement attribute based clustering with this many points to form non-adjacent clusters in order of high/low demand that might also be an option. Open for suggestions(: